# What's the difference between 应急出口 (yìngjí chūkǒu) and 安全出口 (ānquán chūkǒu) which both mean "emergency exit"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Generally I see

> 应急出口
>   <sub>yìngjí chūkǒu</sub>

indicating an emergency exit on a bus, whereas I see

> 安全出口
>   <sub>ānquán chūkǒu</sub>

indicating an emergency exit in a building.  I'm not clear on the difference between them.

**Question**: What's the difference between 应急出口 and 安全出口 which both mean "emergency exit"?

Looking at dict.cn:

- [应急](http://dict.cn/%E5%BA%94%E6%80%A5) = emergency
- [安全](http://dict.cn/%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8) = safety

This makes me suspect that an 应急出口 can only be used in the case of an emergency, whereas an 安全出口 can be used at other times too.  But I may be reading too much into this.

Comment: https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AE%89%E5%85%A8%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%A3/2676747 安全出口 Fire escape vs. https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B4%A7%E6%80%A5%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%A3/8784975 紧急出口 Emergency exit

Comment: bkrs: **应急出口**  **escape hatch** ; emergency exit 翼上应急出口(水上溅落时) escape hatch onto wing during splashdown
**安全出口**  emergency exit(door); exit; escape exit; emergency opening; emergency outlet; fire escape; fire exit **紧急出口** emergency exit 紧急出口标志
紧急出口照明
紧急出口窗
紧急出口窗户
紧急出口门  for images see https://www.google.com/search?q=%E5%BA%94%E6%80%A5%E5%87%BA%E5%8F%A3&client=firefox-b-ab&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiFoK-kkZ3aAhWQ71MKHQ8XDekQsAQILg&biw=1280&bih=913

Comment: Both mean the same things. Regardless whether anyone use the exit for any other purpose, the exit sign mean the exit should never be blocked in any way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are just two different ways to tell you where you can go safely in emergency case.

As you said,

- 应急 = emergency
  (actually emergency is 紧急; 应急 is "for emergency", which is short for 因应紧急)
- 安全 = safety

And they really are

> 应急出口
> (safety) exit for emergency
>
> 安全出口
> safety exit (for emergency)

Answer (score 2):

应急出口 means it’s an escape in case of emergency (literally “emergency exit), while 安全出口 means it’s an safe escape (in case of emergency) (literally “safe exit). 
Both probably indicate an emergency exit, and differences are just in context.